# Typeahead.js, scrollbar and keyboard event

Tags: autocomplete, typeahead.js

I try to use "Typeahead.js" in a project with high keyboard interactivity.

I use the lib to purpose some input suggestions to users. Sometimes there is a lot of results and the suggestion list is scrollable (with this CSS):

```
.tt-suggestions {
  height: 124px !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

But when I use keyboard, the list doesn't scroll although [this evolution](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/209) has been merged.

Is it a bug or i do something wrong ?
I don't find any example on Web.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apply the styles to `.tt-dropdown-menu` (`!important` won't be necessary):

```
.tt-dropdown-menu {
  height: 124px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works ! Thanks a lot ! `!important` is just for example, i don't use it

Comment: It is closing the dropdown when i click on the scroll arrows or the scroll itself . Any help with this ?